# Javascript's getElementById and innerHTML Don't Work Indirectly

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Game Title Goes Here!</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function startGame(){
    document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = ('Testing!');
}
document.body.onload = keyListener(){
    document.getElementById("1").onkeypress = startGame;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="title" name="Game Title" id="0">Game Title</div>
<div tabindex="0" class="gamecontainer" name="Game Container" id="1">
Press any key to start.
</div>
<div class="gamemonitor" name="Game Monitor" id="2">
Game Monitor:
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I doesn't work like I expect it to (I'm using Google Chrome).

It only works if I run it directly, like this:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="gamecontainer" name="Game Container" id="1" onkeypress="document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = ('Testing!')">
Press any key to start.
</div>
<div class="gamemonitor" name="Game Monitor" id="2">
Game Monitor:
</div>
```

I checked over my code tons of times and i cannot find any clear mistakes like typos or anything. If that is the problem then I am sorry to have wasted your time but this is realy buggin' me.

Comment: It think the second way shouldn't work instead of the first, you're mixing with the quotes there... :(

Comment: `keyListener(){}` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.body` doesn't have an `onload` property.  It should be `window.onload` instead.

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("1").onkeypress = startGame;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/9khng/

Comment: It does (at least in chrome) but `document.body` doesn't exist when the script is executed since the script is in the head

Comment: @Esailija: True.  My explanation may not be right, but this was the issue :-P

Comment: @kukac67: You mean mark a question "solved"?  Click the checkmark under the up/down vote arrows.

Answer (score 2):

[Element IDs can't start with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/509663), it's almost definitely contributing to your issue here. Change the IDs in both the HTML and JS to begin with a letter.

Second of all, the `keyListener` line should probably be something like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("newId").onkeypress = startGame;
}
```

Comment: But he's using the same id in the second inline way...?

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
document.body.onload = keyListener(){
    document.getElementById("1").onkeypress = startGame;
}
```

To:

```
document.body.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("1").onkeypress = startGame;
}
```

And, `id` shouldn't begin with a number as it's an invalid HTML.
Chrome seems to overcome this mistake, but it shouldn't be used.

And move the code to the the `<body>` tag or use `window.onload`
`document.body` doesn't exist above the `<body>`.

Comment: i changed the ids to letters and i changed keyListener to function and  it still doesnt work.

Comment: `document.body` doesn't exist at the point the script is called.... use `window.onload`

Comment: @gdoron yeah exactly at the same second xD

Comment: @Esailija. But I edited my answer before the comment, which means => 5 seconds ahead. `:) LOL`

Answer (score 0):

I think IDs can't start with a number.

Comment: You're right, but this isn't the issue here, he's using the same id in the second inline way. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing your "onkeypress" attribute. Your quotes are messed up.

```
onkeypress="document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = ('Testing!')"
```